# Trying to copy table range with criteria

Tags: excel, vba, excel-tables, listobject

Im trying to copy a table range with criteria, however I am not able to define the criteria to copy the desired lines, which consists of copying only the lines where the CC column has data skiping the entire row if CC is empty. I'll just copy ( copy to clipboard ), for paste I'll do it manually for other reasons

[image: My Table]

The lines will always be like this, never with a whole blank line between them like the second image

[image: Not like this]

```
Sub CopyValues()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim bottomA As Long
    Dim srcWS As Worksheet
    Set srcWS = Sheets("CC2")
    
    With srcWS
        bottomA = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For Each rng In .Range("B3:I3" & bottomA)
            If WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Range("B" & rng.Row & ":I" & rng.Row)) > 0 Then
                Range("B" & rng.Row & ":I" & rng.Row)).Copy
            End If
        Next rng
    End With
    
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: 1. Last row in a table (`listObject`) is not the same with the sheet last row on the respective column... 2. Please, edit your question and better describe what you try doing. Do you want copying only **table rows with values on all table columns**? If so, and you only want placing the respective rows in clipboard, you should build a `Union` range containing them, to copy. I cannot understand the meaning of the second picture. I mean, what do you want transmitting by showing it. You should show the existing situation and **what you try accomplishing after processing** in a second one, I think.

Comment: Do you want copying all rows having values in "CC" table column, independent of values on the other columns?

Comment: Yes, if the CC has value, i want the entire row to be copied, even blank cells

Comment: Then, your code can be simplified, not needing any iteration. If the values in column B:B (of the table) are not result of formulas...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Copy Filtered Rows From Excel Table (ListObject)

- The screenshot illustrates the benefits of using an Excel table:

  - The table can be anywhere on the worksheet.
  - You can easily reference a column by its name (header).
  - You can move the column anywhere in the table.

[image]

```vb
Sub CopyFilteredRows()
    
    ' Define constants.

    Const WorksheetName As String = "CC2"
    Const TableName As String = "Tabela452"
    Const CriteriaColumnName As String = "CC"
    Const Criteria As String = "<>" ' non-blanks ('blank' includes 'empty')

    ' Reference the objects ('wb', 'ws' , 'tbl', 'lc')

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(WorksheetName)
    Dim tbl As ListObject: Set tbl = ws.ListObjects(TableName)
    Dim lc As ListColumn: Set lc = tbl.ListColumns(CriteriaColumnName)
    
    ' Reference the filtered rows ('rrg').
    
    Dim rrg As Range
    
    With tbl
        If .ShowAutoFilter Then ' autofilter arrows are turned on
            ' Clear all filters.
            If .AutoFilter.FilterMode Then .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        Else ' autofilter arrows are turned off
            .ShowAutoFilter = True ' turn on the autofilter arrows
        End If
        
        .Range.AutoFilter lc.Index, Criteria
        
        ' Attempt to reference the filtered rows ('rrg').
        On Error Resume Next
            ' Reference the visible cells.
            Set rrg = .DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            ' When columns are hidden, resize to entire rows of the table.
            Set rrg = Intersect(.DataBodyRange, rrg.EntireRow)
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        ' Clear the filter.
        .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    End With

    ' Invalidate the filtered rows.        
    If rrg Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No filtered rows.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Copy.

    rrg.Copy
    
End Sub
```

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your time and work on this code. It worked almost perfectly for my needs, only point: how do I copy the entire table row, including the hidden columns (C, E, F, G and H), because they exist so that there is a spacing when pasting the copied content.

Comment: In the `On Error` block, right below the line `Set rrg = .DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`, add the line `Set rrg = Intersect(.DataBodyRange, rrg.EntireRow)`. Fixed. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Use Union to select a non-contiguous range.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CopyValues()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range, rngB As Range
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("CC2")
    With ws.ListObjects("Tabela452")
        For Each rngB In .ListColumns("CC").DataBodyRange
            If Len(rngB) > 0 Then
                If rng Is Nothing Then
                    Set rng = rngB.Resize(1, 8) ' B to I
                Else
                    Set rng = Union(rng, rngB.Resize(1, 8))
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With
    
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Nothing selected", vbExclamation
    Else
        rng.Select
        rng.Copy
        MsgBox "range copied " & rng.Address, vbInformation
    End If
        
End Sub
```

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your time and work on this code.  Your code is capturing all column B without respecting table452, how can I limit it to capture only column CC (B3:B13)?

Comment: On a side note, as we are taught not to use `Select` we kind of forget how to use it to write efficient code that doesn't depend on what is selected or activated. Before selecting a range, you need to make sure that its worksheet is active. Before selecting a worksheet, you need to make sure that its workbook is active. Also, after combining the ranges, you usually want to make sure that anything was combined. I know you know how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Please, test the next adapted code. It does not need any iteration:

```
Sub CopyValues()
    Dim rngCopy As Range, tbl As ListObject
    Dim srcWS As Worksheet: Set srcWS = Sheets("CC2")
    Set tbl = srcWS.ListObjects(1) 'use here the table  name, if more than 1
       On Error Resume Next 'for the case of no any value in the table first column
        Set rngCopy = tbl.DataBodyRange.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        'or
        'Set rngCopy = tbl.DataBodyRange.Columns(tbl.ListColumns("CC").Index).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
       On Error GoTo 0
       If Not rngCopy Is Nothing Then  'for the case of no any values in table first column
                Intersect(rngCopy.EntireRow, tbl.DataBodyRange).Copy
       Else
                MsgBox "No any value in column ""CC""..."
       End If
End Sub
```

As I said in my comment, it works if the values in column "CC" are not result of formulas...

Comment: @Glad I could help! But you must learn that you can be helped only if you help us to clearly understand what you try accomplishing... :)

Comment: Much sorry! I will take this advice for my future questions!

Comment: @VBasic2008 What do you mean by "non-empty blank cells"?  I must confess I did not look at the other answers... I did not understand what he tries accomplishing and I asked a clarification question. I could see its clarification some minutes before and prepared an answer as I had in mind when asked. I could not see any filter in his pictures. I cannot see it neither now, looking again... Am I missing something, from this point of view?

Comment: @VBasic2008 No, no, I did not feel being criticized... I really was not sure about what (else than `'`) may exist. I thought about `'` (to format the cell content as text), but I could not imagine that you are referring to it, since it is very improbable that somebody may use it in this way... And I do not think that `=""` will be included. As I mentioned, the code works only if values are not results of formulas... And I looked now to your code, which is interesting, but I still do not understand why putting in discussion the filtering. I also like sharing interesting info...:)

Answer (score 1):

For the criteria when looking for empty values, you can always use LEN to check the number of characters in the cell.

If it is greater than 0 it means that something is in there, you can also set it to an exact amount of digits to be more precise.

Something like this should work:

```
Sub CopyValues()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim bottomA As Long
    Dim srcWS As Worksheet
    Dim currentRow As Long
    Const ccColumn As Long = 2
    Const startingRow As Long = 3
    
    Set srcWS = Sheets("CC2")
    
    With srcWS
    
        bottomA = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For currentRow = startingRow To bottomA
            If Len(.Cells(currentRow, ccColumn).Value) > 0 Then
                .Range("B" & currentRow & ":I" & currentRow).Copy
            End If
        Next currentRow
        
    End With
    
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your time and help. Your code did not respect Table452, he copied data that was below it, I believe that the criterion selected a different format to be copied